# Is it possible to make a Jar that could use on both Android and Java SE(EE)?

Tags: java, android, cross-platform

I have been asked a question: **"Is it possible to write an SDK(as Jar) that could uses on both Standard Java(SE/EE) and the Android enviorment?"**. I recall some slides of memory that I encounter few years ago which tell me it is not possible because there are few type or method that are not exist on Both platform, but I totally forgot what they are.

Could anyone tell me is this (or not) possible to make a jar that could runs on both environment?

Comment: you can't run a jar file on android but can use it as a library

Comment: Hmm, I correct the title now.

Comment: you can use it but of course there are platform-specific restriction such as you can't use libraries written on java8+, that use swing/awt/ect, and so on